# Slow application performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The problem I am encountering is that the application performance is very slow because I believe their are to many diagrams running in the background, in other words to much is going on inside index.html.

**How can only make one diagram to run only when the user is viewing it, and hold the rest idle until they are selected?**

I have two HTML files and five JavaScript files.

1. Index.html
2. NavigationList.html
3. Diagram1.js
4. Diagram2.js
5. Diagram3.js
6. Diagram4.js
7. Diagram5.js

This is index.html, here I have included 5 diagrams that is view-able inside the `<body>` as ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs-1.6.2/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <!--Import diagrams-->
    <script src="diagram1.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram2.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram3.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram4.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram5.js"></script>

    <script> 
        $(function(){
        $("#selectTable").load("NavigationList.html"); // Navigation list for diagrams  
        }); 
    </script> 

</head>
<body>
      <div id="toolbar"></div>
      <div id="diagram1"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram2"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram3"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram4"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram5"  class="table"></div>             
      <div id="NavigationList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is NavigationList.html, it consists of two parts. The first part is the html content that is responsible for displaying the list for the user. The second part is JQuery that handles the click events. I am suspicious, and believe that maybe the problem could be inside JQuery code, since it only runs the diagrams individually by "display:none/block" but this stidiagrams are still running in the background, so I need to find a way to stop them in running simultaneously?

```
</div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <!--Set this inside a div to individuelly choose-->
        <div id='list_row1' data-row="1"><li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li></div>
        <div id='list_row2' data-row="2"><li class="list-group-item">Cylinder Pressure</li></div>
        <div id='list_row3' data-row="3"><li class="list-group-item">Mass Air Flow</li></div>
        <div id='list_row4' data-row="4"><li class="list-group-item">Flywheel</li></div>
        <div id='list_row5' data-row="5"><li class="list-group-item">Lambda</li></div>
        <div id='list_row6' data-row="6"><li class="list-group-item">Knock</li></div>
        <!--<div id='list_row7' data-row="7"><li class="list-group-item">Camshaft position</li></div>-->
        <div id='list_row8' data-row="8"><li class="list-group-item">Fluid Temperature</li></div>
        <div id='list_row9' data-row="9"><li class="list-group-item">Fluid Pressure</li></div>
        <div id='list_row10' data-row="10"><li class="list-group-item">Throttle Position</li></div>
        <div id='list_row11' data-row="11"><li class="list-group-item">Manifold Absolute Pressure</li></div>
        <div id='list_row12' data-row="12"><li class="list-group-item">Flex Fuel</li></div>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
        var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('#table' + row).addClass('active');          
    });             
 });
</script>
```

This is diagram1.js out of 5 other diagrams. The file is included in index.html. The code here is just responsible for displaying the diagram with some random generated data. But if 5 diagrams are included in index.html, this slows down the performance.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
        var dps = []; 
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("diagram1",
        { 
        data: [
          {        
            type: "spline",
            dataPoints: dps
          }]

        });
        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100; 
        var updateInterval = 1; 
        var dataLength = 50; 

        var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
                dps.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: yVal       
                });
                xVal++;
            }; 
            if (dps.length > dataLength )
            {
                dps.shift();             
            }
            chart.render();     
        };

        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 

        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 
});
```

Comment: The `updateInterval` is one millisecond. __That's__ the performance problem.

Comment: This might be useful > https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I do not believe so. What I did was delete 4 diagrams and test one. This increased the performance, so I strongly believe that the problem lies on how many diagrams that are running at the same time.

Comment: You are redrawing the diagrams 1,000 times per second. This is the actual problem. If you try detecting the scroll position and determine when a diagram is in the viewport before updating it, you've still got a diagram updating 1,000 times per second, plus an `onscroll` event handler that can execute up to 50 times in one second. With your current update interval, no amount of lazy loading or activation is going to make this better. Even with one diagram on the page, what is your CPU usage like? I bet it's pretty high.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that time in JavaScript is done by the milliseconds and not by seconds.

When you call `var updateInterval = 1;` you are telling it to run every 1 milliseconds.

That means for every 1 second you are asking it to run 1,000 times.  This is likely the bottleneck.

If that is not your intention, you may want to try a larger value.  1 second = 1000 milliseconds.

Try updating your code to `var updateInterval = 1000;`.

Here is an additional resource on JavaScript Timing Events: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: I understand this, thank you. But I would really want figure out how I can only run one diagram while holding the rest idle.

Comment: You can create a callback function.  When diagram1 is finished, have it then call diagram2 and so on.  But even then, it is generally not best practice to call a function 1,000 times per second.

Comment: Hmm, I could try that. But I want the user freely to navigate between the diagrams.

Comment: `var updateInterval = 1`, is responsible for updating the interval. That means to receive data in 1 ms. I do not see how this could be a problem when I have already tested diagram5 while emptying the code in diagram1-4, with the result of running in high performance? I simply want the user to invoke the diagram he/she wants to view once at time. While holding the rest diagrams at idle (receiving no data)